# SSRS 2012 web service configuration

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

We are consuming SSRS 2005 reports using     http:///reportserver/reportservice.asmx. When I open this in browser, it shows WSDL, which is working fine.

Now we are trying to migrate to SSRS 2012, in Configuration manager found the webservice URL as: http:///

based on that, we are trying to consume new reports using URL: http:////ReportServer/ReportService.asmx

when I open this new URL in browser it is showing "Reports" folder instead of WSDL.

any idea about the issue?, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do your URLs actually include four slashes at the beginning?  If so, that could be a problem (but, perhaps, not THE problem).

Comment: sorry, that was a typo, there are only two slashes. there is no issue in URL, SSRS 2012 URL shows "Reports" folder, and I'm able to navigate to individual reports. It seems to be a configuration issue, but not sure how to fix it and get actual WSDL.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`http://server/reportserver/ReportService2010.asmx?wsdl` and  `http://server/reportserver/ReportExecution2005.asmx?wsdl`

as mentioned in this post

http://jaliyaudagedara.blogspot.ca/2012/05/accessing-report-server-using-report.html